# Rails 4 - Complex Model Relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

*Preface:*  This question is quite specific.  I've been racking my brain over this--  I think I need a guru for this one.

*The Concept*: A "test-taker" needs to answer a multiple-choice question (usually with >1 correct answer).  The user selects the correct answers (pictures) and then click **"Submit"**.

Sorta like to this:

[image: Which ones need baking?]

***My Problem:*** I don't know the best way to *collect and store* (and then eventually *retrieve*) the data on this sort of thing.  Specifically:

- Which user attempted to answer this question?
- Which pictures did the user select?
- Which user-selected pictures were correct/incorrect?
- Was this question overall correct? (E.g., the user was only partially correct?)

***My Table Structure*:**

```
users
  id
===================================================
templates
  id
  prompt                 #"Which one needs baking?"
===================================================
choices                  #e.g., the image
  id
  name
  image
=================================================== 
template_assignments    #a join table between templates and choices
  id
  choice_id
  template_id
  correct               #boolean - Is this image the correct response?
===================================================
responses               #this is where I am LOST
  id
  user_id
  template_id
  --Not sure what to do with this table, maybe something like:
  response_1
  response_1_correct    #boolean
  etc....
  overall_correct       #boolean
  -- Or would I need some other type of join table?
```

***My Relationships:***

```
  class Choice < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :template_assignments
    has_many :templates, :through => :template_assignments
  end

  class Template < ActiveRecord:Base
    has_many :template_assignments, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :choices, :through => :template_assignments
    has_many :responses
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :template_assignments, allow_destroy: true
  end

  class TemplateAssignment < ActiveRecord:Base
    belongs_to :template
    belongs_to :choice
  end

  class Response < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :template
  end
```

Any suggestions on how define the relationships between these models would be very helpful!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would set up your project. You need a couple join tables

```
Templates    
* id
* prompt

Choices    
* id
* name
* image

Responses   
* template_id
* user_id
* score

TemplateChoices
( there should be 4 rows for the question above )
* template_id
* choice_id

TemplateSolutions
( if there are three correct answers, then there should only be 3 rows)  
* template_id
* choice_id
```

if you want to store the choices the user made

```
ChoiceResponses
* choice_id   
* response_id
```

I'll update this post to help you for any questions you have.
(BTW I would use 'Rails join table naming conventions as much as possible')